# How to retain dropdown's selected value after page post back in YII?

Tags: php, view, yii, modal-dialog, dropdownbox

I have dropdown that is binding in modal. using the below code:

```
public function getYears()
{
    for ($i=date('Y');$i>=2012;$i--)
    {
            $years["{$i}"]="{$i}";
    }
   return $years;                  
}
```

and my view is :

```
 <div class="row">
 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'year'); ?>
 <?php echo CHtml::activedropDownList($model,'years',$model->getYears(),array('class'=>'myClass')); ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model,'year'); ?>

 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
 <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
'name'=>'name',
'source'=>$this->createUrl('reports/autocompleteTest'),
'options'=>array(
        'delay'=>300,
        'minLength'=>2,      
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
),
));
?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?> 

  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Status'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'is_active',array("1"=>"Active","0"=>"InActive")); ?> 
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'Status'); ?>

   </div>
<div class="summary_btn buttons"> <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Search'); ?> </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Now when i click on a button `Search`, my page is making post back. And it rebinds the dropdown list.

I dont know how can i retain the selected value in dropdown after the button click.

Comment: means you want to retrieve the selected choice after the page refresh also ??

Comment: @Ninad yes i want to retain the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `setAttributes` of your model from `$_POST`, so Yii will reassign model values to form components, just like with saving models, but without save:

```php
public function someAction()
{
    // load model somewhere
    $model = $this->_loadModel();
    if($_POST['modelName'])
    {
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['modelName']);
    }
    $this->render('someView', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

After comments I noticed that you have your model with `getYears` method, which Yii uses as getter for attribute `years`, as [explained in getters and setters tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/). You should rename it for example `getYearRanges`. And ensure you have `years` attribute in your model to hold current `years` value, and have rule as [in HarryFink answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231774/133408).

Comment: where i need to implement this code ? on buttons(search) click or somewhere else.

Comment: In the controller action. Don't forget to set the attribute to safe (or apply any validation rule) in your model rules or the setAttributes wont work.

Comment: You shold put this in you `search` or whatever named is your `postback` action. Thanks Harry for your comment, it is very important to have at least `safe` rule.

Comment: im getting the followi
ng error : "Property "Users.years" is read only. "

Comment: It's because you have name conflict with attribute `years`, please read [article about getters and setters](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/), ill soon update answer a bit to show you what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

In the action:

```
$model->setAttributes($_POST[get_class($model)]);
```

In the model:

```
function rules(){
    return array(
        //other rules
        array('years', 'safe'), //or any other validation
    )
}
```

Comment: getting the following error:  "Property "Users.years" is read only. "

Comment: Yes, because you have a getYears() method on your model. Rename it something like: getYearOptions()